# Using blend trees for a simple 2d character

Tags: 2d, animation, unity

Let me start by saying that I'm not a animator and basically have no idea what I'm talking about. The character in the game has 3 states : indle(looks at camera) walk left and walk right. I've set up the transitions for all states but now I want to know how to blend from the idle state to each one of the walking states. This is how my animator looks like :[image]

Comment: What you need is to put conditions on the arrows that goes from/to idle - walk r/l so for example you can use time from walk to idle and your condition of walking (a key pressed) on the other side

Comment: I have done that and it works. What I want is to blend the states WHILE they are in transition so that the character does not flip abruptly when a state changes.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the transition duration?

Comment: @UriPopov oh! then you just have to adjust the parameters of the transition! :D Give them more time so it won't make that 'jump'

Comment: @Megasa3 yes I'm already experimenting with that as per Vadim Tatarnikov's suggestion. It seems this is what I need.

Comment: @UriPopov ups didn't see the Vadim comment sorry.  well as I said, just increase the time ;)